# Need help understanding how using both a stack and binary search tree is relevant in an advanced Reverse Polish Notation program

Tags: c

I have a project assignment in C and I'm trying to think of ways of how I should go about doing it.  I could try to explain all of the parts of the assignment but I'd guess it'd make more sense just to quote the entire thing:

> NAME rpcalc - a simple RPN calculator
>
> NAME
>
> rpcalc - a simple RPN calculator and conversion tool
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> rpcalc [-e | -c | -g] expression
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The rpcalc utility performs several possible manipulations of an
>   arithmetic expression written in reverse polish notation, writing the
>   results to standard output.
>
> By default (i.e. if no options are passed to the program), the utility
>   evaluates the expression. This behavior is also used in the event that
>   user passes the command line option -e to the program.
>
> If the user passes the command line option -c, then the program
>   converts the expression into its equivalent infix notation,
>   parenthesizing subexpressions only as necessary.
>
> If the user passes the command line option g, then the program
>   generates a series of instructions in a mock assembly language which
>   if performed by a hypothetical computer, would evaluate the
>   expression. The instruction sequence output by the program assumes the
>   existence of an infinite number of machine registers.
>
> INPUT SYNTAX
>
> The rpcalc utility assumes that input expression makes use of the
>   following binary operators integers:
>
> A - denoting addition S - denoting subtraction X - denoting
>   multiplication D - denoting integer division M - denoting the modulus
>   operation For example, the program may be run as follows:
>
> rpcalc 5 4 + X 18 S 5 D 3 52
>
> rpcalc -c 5 4 + X 18 S 5 D 3 ((5 + 4) * 18 - 5) / 3
>
> MOCK ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE
>
> The assembly language output through the use of the -g option is
>   fairly simple consisting of the following instructions:
>
> MOV R# VALUE
>
> -R# denotes a numbered register (e.g. R1, R2, ...)
>
> -VALUE denotes an integer
>
> -Instructions of this form are read as: "move VALUE into register R#".
>
> ADD R#1 R#2 R#3
>
> -R#1, R#2, and R#3 denote distinct registers
>
> -Instructions of this form are read as: "add the contents of register R2 to the
>
> -contents of register R1, saving the results to register R3"
>
> SUB R#1 R#2 R#3
>
> -R#1, R#2, and R#3 denote distinct registers
>
> -Instructions of this form are read as: "subtract the contents of register R2      from the contents of register R1, saving the results
>   to register R3"
>
> MUL R#1 R#2 R#3
>
> -R#1, R#2, and R#3 denote distinct registers
>
> -Instructions of this form are read as: "multiply the contents of register R1 by the contents of register R2, saving the results to
>   register R3"
>
> DIV R#1 R#2 R#3
>
> -R#1, R#2, and R#3 denote distinct registers
>
> -Instructions of this form are read as: "divide the contents of register R1 by the contents of register R2, saving the quotient to
>   register R3"
>
> MOD R#1 R#2 R#3
>
> -R#1, R#2, and R#3 denote distinct registers
>
> -Instructions of this form are read as: "divide the contents of register R1 by the contents of register R2, saving the remainder to
>   register R3"
>
> WRT R#1
>
> -R#1 denotes a register
>
> -Instructions of this form are read as: "write the contents of R1 to the screen"

As you can see it's a little bit more than a simple RPN calculator.  We had to do a basic RPN calculator as a lab earlier this semester and I just used a stack implementation.  For this program, our professor is telling us the best way to go about doing it is using both a stack along with a binary search tree.  I was hoping someone could break it down to me why I would need both of these data structures for this program, or why it would be most necessary.  As far as I can see, I should be able to complete the program using either data type, and fail to see how using both would be relevant.  If someone could explain what they think about this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that a stack would be sufficient for a pure RPN implementation. However, there seems to be also support for parenthised infix notation which would require to build a syntax tree first before processing.
Also, you could search the functions related to each instruction token using a binary tree (I suppose you just had a simple `switch .. case`).

However, that is just a rough guess.

Comment: Your answer definitely gave me something to think about.  Thanks.